# Why do my Tensorflow neural networks act so slow after I start training it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

My **Tensorflow neural network** gets progressively slower as it trains. Every time I train the network, it acts slower and slower.

**After the 30th or so iteration of training, it becomes unbearably slow** and it's virtually unusable. By the 60th or so iteration, the program stop responding.

I didn't think that this neural network is that complex. It's a simple three layer network put together with Tensorflow.

Do you guys have any idea how to go about this problem?

```
import tensorflow as tf

hidden_1_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([37500, 500])),
                  'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([500]))}
hidden_2_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([500, 250])),
                  'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([250]))}
hidden_3_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([250, 125])),
                  'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([125]))}
output_layer = {'weights': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([125, 1])),
                'biases': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))}

class ImageNN():
    def train(self, array, target):
        x = tf.placeholder('float', name='x')
        l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
        l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)
        l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
        l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)
        l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
        l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)
        output = tf.add(tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']), output_layer['biases'])
        output = tf.nn.sigmoid(output)
        cost = tf.square(output-target)
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)
        array = array.reshape(1, 37500)
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: array})
            sess.close()
        del x, l1, l2, output, cost, optimizer

    #Do computations with our artificial nueral network
    def predict(self, data):          #Input data is of size (37500,)
        x = tf.placeholder('float', name='x')    #get data into the right rank (dimensions), this is just a placeholder, it has no values
        l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
        l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)
        l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
        l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)
        l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
        l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)
        output = tf.add(tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']), output_layer['biases'])
        output = tf.nn.sigmoid(output)
        data = data.reshape(1, 37500)
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            theOutput = sess.run(output, feed_dict={x: data})
            sess.close()
        del x, l1, l2, output, data
        return theOutput
```

Comment: 1) try training a simple working mlp first https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/neural_network_raw.py , this proves that your environment is setup correctly. 2) bump up the input data size in the simple mlp to a comparable input size as your actual input data size, this tests if your hardware is capable of doing the number crunching you expected it to. If training is consistently slow, then its just a matter of updating the hardware.  If training is not that slow, then most likely there are bugs in your code.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a memory issue. You're not deleting l3 or array in your train method, or l3 in your predict method. I don't think this is the cause of the issue as this should get thrown away by the Python interpreter anyway I believe.

How are you calling this class? It might be that you're holding onto the output in memory and it's getting very large.

Comment: I'm calling the class like so. NN = ImageNN() and later, NN.train(array=trainingArray, target=1) and NN.predict(a). What do you mean, holding onto the output in memory?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that every time you call `train()`, tf is reconstructing the graph. Try to define your network, loss, and trainer outside the `train()` function, as well as `predict()` function.